# What reserved IP addresses exist on a local private network?

Tags: ipv4, ip, ip-address

For example: `192.168.*.1` is reserved, but for what? What device? What others exist on private or other networks?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no reserved addresses on private networks, other than the network and broadcast addresses (the same as any other network). Where did you get the idea that `192.168.*.1` is reserved?

The [*IANA IPv4 Special-Purpose Address Registry*](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv4-special-registry/iana-ipv4-special-registry.xhtml) details all the special IPv4 address ranges, and information about each.

Comment: Then why is *.1 always occupied?

Comment: Many companies assign either the first or last usable host address on a network to the default gateway assigned to the hosts on the network. This is not required, and a gateway, or any other host, could be assigned to any usable host address on a network.